# PermCheck codility. O(N) time complexity

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, time-complexity

Hi i have this solution for PermCheck codility. Here is the link which includes the question: https://codility.com/demo/results/demo73YNCU-8FK/

I got 100% for it but i got a time complexity of O(N * log(N)) or O(N). 
How could i make this code O(N)? Could you also give a brief description of what makes code O(N)? Thankyou.

Code here for shortcut:

```
    Array.Sort(A);
    if(A[0] == 1 && A.Length == 1) return 1;
    if(A[0] != 1) return 0;

    int n = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
    {    
        if(i < A.Length - 1)
        {
            if(A[i+1] == A[i] + 1)
            {
                n += 1;
            }
            else 
            {
                return 0;   
            }
        }

    }
    return 1;
```

Comment: I think this would be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thankyou Abrixas2. I'll post it there

Comment: nlogn is because Array.Sort() use quick sort I guess..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a bool array which has the same size as the input, N, and leave all elements as the default false value. Loop through every element X of the input. If X is greater than N then return false. If array[N-1] is true, return false. Otherwise set array[N-1] to true. Repeat. This is O(N).

Explanation: First, if you have a permutation, then you need elements 1..N, but if any element is larger than N, then surely some elements are missing. Second, if an element occurs twice, it's a problem, that's why we create the bool array to remember already seen elements.

Answer (score 1):

My python solution (doesn't need additional libraries, looks pythonic and not difficult to understand by others):

```py
    def solution(A): return 1 if len(set(A)) == len(A) == sorted(A)[-1] else 0
```

It can be simplified to:

```py
    def solution(A):
        if len(set(A)) == len(A):
            if len(A) == sorted(A)[-1]:
                return 1
        return 0
```

I checked two moments:

1: Length of set from array (set can't have duplicates) is equals to length of initial array

Arrays passed (no duplicates):
[1, 3, 2, 4], [4, 3, 2, 5]

Arrays failed:
[1, 1, 2, 4], [5, 6, 6, 1]

2: Length of initial array is equals to last element in sorted array

Arrays passed:
[1, 2, 3, 4]: Length is equal to last element => return 1

Arrays failed:
[2, 3, 4, 5]: Length is not equal to last element => return 0

This code doesn't work if A contains 0 or negative elements, but according to task details: each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].

Codility shows 100% and O(N) or O(N * log(N))

Tried to make it O(N) (suggested by fejesjoco):

```py
def solution(A):
        array_length = len(A)
        seen_values = [False] * array_length
        for x in A:
            if x > array_length:
                return 0
            else:
                if seen_values[x - 1]:
                    return 0
                else:
                    seen_values[x - 1] = True
        return 1
```

Codility result 100% Detected time complexity: O(N) or O(N * log(N))

Both codes shows equal result and time complexity. Maybe codility can't evaluate it right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 100/100 answer:

same Idea as @fejesjoco

https://codility.com/demo/results/demoNR485D-33P/

You can change int to long to get performance.

> ```
>     public int solution(int[] A)
>     {
>         // idea: add to set,dictionary. Count the size and compare to N.
>         // dedupe data when needed. 
>         var set = new HashSet<int>();
>         var max = int.MinValue;
>
>         foreach (var item in A)
>         {
>             if (set.Contains(item)) return 0;
>
>             set.Add(item);
>             if (item > max) max = item;
>         }
>         return set.Count == max ? 1 : 0;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution that scored 100% in correctness and performance.

def solution(A):
    arraylength = len(A)

```
if (arraylength > 100000):
    raise ValueError("Out of bound range")    

arr = sorted(A)

for i in range(arraylength):

    if (arr[i] != i+1):
        return 0

return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this questions is asked long time ago but it is still active in codility.

Possible solution:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    return (Enumerable.Range(1, A.Length).Except(A).Count() == 0) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by **fejesjoco**,

```
Boolean[] bln = new Boolean[A.Length];       

for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
{
    if (A[i] > A.Length) // more than array length
        return 0;
    if (bln[A[i]-1]) // same value twice
        return 0;
    bln[A[i]-1] = true;
}
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution that scores 100% in both correctness and performance, and is easy to understand. Note that `list(set(A))` produces an array that holds all the unique values in A.

```
def solution(A):
  N = len(A)
  if max(A) > N or min(A) != 1:
    return 0 
  elif len(list(set(A))) != len(A):
    return 0
  else: 
    return 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This was my solution, it scored 100%. Do not forget to add "using System.Linq".

```
int distinctLength = A.Distinct().ToArray().Length;
// The array length should equal to the distinct array length which is also the maximum value in array A.
if (A.Length == distinctLength && distinctLength == A.Max()) { return 1; }
return 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

Swift Solution 100%

```
public func solution(_ A : inout [Int]) -> Int {
    // write your code in Swift 4.2.1 (Linux)

    let sorted = A.sorted()

    for (index, value) in sorted.enumerated() {

        if index+1 != value {

            return 0
        }
    }

    return 1
}
```